# Using Join without affecting Data Count

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, join

I have a problem where I need to join a table in my Controller using Linq but when i join the table, the data is affected and some of it is removed or not included , I think my Join is filtering the Table and decreases the Data Fetched using Linq

WHAT type of Joining will i use? Cross Join , Left Outer Join or Right Join??

```
   WHAT I AM GETTING: 
                              POSITION TABLE                         
    POSITION_ID |Location_id|POSITION _Name|  APPLIED or NOT (buttons) | 
          1     |    1      |  DRIVER      |               YES         |
          3     |    3      |  NURSE       |               YES         |
          4     |    4      |  POLICE      |               YES         |

    DESIRED OUTPUT: 

                              POSITION TABLE                         
    POSITION_ID |Location_id|POSITION _Name|  APPLIED or NOT (buttons) | 
          1     |    1      |  DRIVER      |               YES         |
          2     |    2      |  ANALYSTS    |               NO          |
          3     |    3      |  NURSE       |               YES         |
          4     |    4      |  POLICE      |               YES         |
          5     |    5      |  DOCTOR      |               NO          |
```

I hope someone can Help Me

This is my Linq Statement

```
var newPositionList = (from a in db.Position
                 join b in db.Position_Location
                 on a.ID equals b.PositionId            
                 join c in db.Employer
                 on a.EmployerID equals c.ID
                 join d in db.EmployerLocation
                 on b.LocationId equals d.ID
                 join e in db.WorkersApplied    <--------------- Joined Table
                 on a.ID equals e.PositionID
                 where b.LogicalDelete == false
                 && a.LogicalDelete == false
                 && c.LogicalDelete == false
                 && d.LogicalDelete == false
                 select new
                 {
                     a.ID,
                     CompanyName = c.Company_Name,
                     ClientId = c.ClientID,
                     EmployerID = c.ID,
                     LocationId = b.LocationId,
                     e.LogicalDelete

                 }).Distinct().ToList();

            var PositionInfoListNew = new List<PositionInfo>();

            foreach (var row in newPositionList)
            {
                var pos = new PositionInfo
                {
                    ID = row.ID,
                    ClientID = row.ClientId,
                    userId = row.userId.ToString(),
                    EmployerID = row.EmployerID,
                    Company = row.CompanyName,
                    LocationId = row.LocationId,
                    LogicalDelete = row.LogicalDelete
                };
                PositionInfoListNew.Add(pos);
            }


            return Json(PositionInfoListNew.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: try with  `left join e in db.WorkersApplied`

Comment: @catalinetu cannot use `left join e in db.WorkersApplied` causing unknown token

Comment: Take a look at this for LEFT JOIN in Linq: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Comment: @shree.pat18 what do you think will become my condition in `select new` for `e.LogicalDelete`?

Comment: is this linq2sql or entity framework?